# Issue with docker login to nexus with non admin user

Tags: docker, nexus3

I have an issue with the nexus docker login using non-admin users. For example:

```
docker login illinXXXX.corp.amdocs.com:XXXX -u mb_cpq -p XXXXXX
Error response from daemon: Get http://illinXXXX.corp.amdocs.com:XXXX/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I am able to do it only with an admin user:

```
docker login illinXXXX.corp.amdocs.com:XXXX -u admin -p XXXX
Login Succeeded
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `roles` for the user, I had to move the `LDAP realm` to be at the top of the list. Since it’s a local user, it tries to authenticate using LDAP, and by the times it gets it, we got the timeout.